# Gradle 2 android projects using same library

Tags: java, android, build, gradle

I have the following structure

```
MainProjectRoot
  Android Project 1:
     ...
  Android Project 2:
     ...
  Shared Library:
     ...
```

The library project is shared between both of the Android projects. I am trying to convert things to work with the new build system.

This is what export from eclipse generated for the build.gradle for Project1.

```
compile project(':D::workspace:MainProjectRoot:shared-library')
```

How do i fix this reference?

i tried this but it expects the library to be inside the Project1 Folder if i leave it out as

```
compile project(':shared-library')
```

Answer (score 1):

The export from Eclipse is broken on Windows when dealing with multi-module projects. We are fixing this.

In the meantime ensure you have the settings.gradle file under MainProjectRoot/
It should contain:

```
include 'project1'
include 'project2'
include 'shared-library'
```

(or whatever those folder names are).

Then you change the dependency line to be

```
compile project(':shared-library')
```

Comment: Ok, i think i did that and it compiled. Another thing i am having issues with after i fixed this is that i cannot find a way to run the app as an android application. i can only run tests... I compared it with a new project which runs as its supposed to and everything is configured the same.. Thanks!

Comment: yes. in Android studio under windows, when i exported my current project from Eclipse and did what you suggested above.